# "Undeclared identifier" in Delphi 7 - what must I do?

Tags: delphi, delphi-7, undeclared-identifier

```
procedure TForm1.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
showmassage('Create by rihsano');
end;
```

Delphi reports the following error:

```
 [Error] Unit1.pas(38): Undeclared identifier: 'showmassage'
```

One more question: what is "undeclared identifier"?

Comment: "Undeclared identifier" is an identifier that has not been declared.

Comment: @Safa You should not edit error messages in questions, it would hide the real problem (as it definitely does with your edit).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Replace `showmassage` with `ShowMessage` (case isn't important, but spelling is!).

"Undeclared identifier" means that Delphi cannot find the declaration that tells it what `showmassage` is, so it highlights it as an item that hasn't been declared.

Comment: still say [Error] Unit1.pas(38): Undeclared identifier: 'Showmassage' , any solution ?

Comment: The solution is that you carefully read the answer again and do what it says. You are trying to to display a message box. You are **not** trying to get a leg rub.

Comment: Please re-read my answer carefully - you need to replace the first `a` with an `e`.

Comment: yeah my fault i'm sorry , now it work thanks ^_^ , good bless you

Comment: And for the next time, in the case that Keith mentioned: if you click on the word, hit Ctrl-F1, you get online help telling you (among other things) what unit the procedure/type is identified in - that's the unit to add to your Uses clause. Try it now with ShowMessage.